# Windows message loop and server loop

Tags: c++, winapi

I made a window using the Win32 API and it needs to enter a message loop:

```
while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

How do I create a socket server and start receiving clients, if my main thread is processing UI messages?

I tried putting all of the server code in a thread using `CreateThread()` from `WinMain()`, but it just crashes with an error:

> Exception thrown at 0x00000000 in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.

Here is the thread code:

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    // Initialize Winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    auto iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    addrinfo hints;
    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    PADDRINFOA pAddrInfo = nullptr;
    iResult = getaddrinfo(nullptr, PORT, &hints, &pAddrInfo);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (true) {
        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        auto ListenSocket = socket(pAddrInfo->ai_family, pAddrInfo->ai_socktype, pAddrInfo->ai_protocol);
        if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(pAddrInfo);
            WSACleanup();
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        // Setup the TCP listening socket
        iResult = bind(ListenSocket, pAddrInfo->ai_addr, static_cast<int>(pAddrInfo->ai_addrlen));
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            freeaddrinfo(pAddrInfo);
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        freeaddrinfo(pAddrInfo);

        iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        // Accept a client socket
        auto ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, nullptr, nullptr);
        if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ListenSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        // No longer need server socket
        closesocket(ListenSocket);

        // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
        for (;;)
        {
            char recvbuf[1] = { 0 };
            auto cbLen = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0);

            if (cbLen > 0) {
                if (recvbuf[0] == 0xDA)
                {
                    Hide();
                }

                continue;
            }
            else if (cbLen == 0) {
                printf("Connection closing...\n");
                break;
            }
            else {
                printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return EXIT_FAILURE;
            }
        }

        // shutdown receive operations since we're done
        iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_RECEIVE);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        // cleanup
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
    }
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the rest of your code (I can't see ThreadProc and CreateThread)? Where do you get the exception?

Comment: I see exception thrown at 0x00000000 - is your ThreadProc NULL? I mean when you call CreateThread, what is the exact value of the parameter telling the starting address of the new thread?

Comment: There's a defect in your code, but you didn't show any relevant code

Comment: Here is my ThreadProc code: http://pastebin.com/StRxsuHe

Comment: We aren't here for personal debugging with off site links. If you can't ask the entire question here, then it's not a valid question. Make a [mcve].

Comment: Well, `WSAAsyncSelect` is how you would create a server and start receiving clients on a thread that is processing UI messages.

Comment: @ChrisBecke That is the answer I was looking for. Please add an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very confusing question as it asks one question in the title, but the content addresses a different problem (threads crashing).

To address the primary question: Microsoft did add a way to handle socket communications in a GUI thread friendly way: [WSAAsyncSelect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741540(v=vs.85).aspx). This will send socket events as messages to your applications message queue - typically an invisible window is created to handle the messages.

Comment: The asker might have requested you write this answer but it doesn't answer the question asked.

Comment: The first actual line that is a question in the post is literally: "How do I create a socket server and start receiving clients, if my main thread is processing UI messages?" Which is - admittedly - then followed up with a lot of noise about threads.